# distributed processing api like multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, distributed-computing

I am considering the implementation of a light weight distributed processing framework, which has similar api with [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) in Python. An example is as follow:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
#
# distributed processing demo api
#
from dprocessing import Pool, SSHBackend


def woker(*args, **kwargs):
    print args
    print kwargs

ssh_config = {
    'artisans': [
        {'host': '172.18.217.1', 'username': 'user',
            'password': 'pass', 'cores': 2},
        {'host': '172.18.217.2', 'username': 'user',
            'password': 'pass', 'cores': 4},
    ],
}
backend = SSHBackend(**ssh_config)

pool = Pool(backend)
pool.map(woker, range(10)) # run 10 jobs in 6 processes by 2 artisans
```

Do [these projects](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DistributedProgramming) can achieve such kind of goal that running jobs in multi-computers with simple api? And would you give me some advises to implement the framework?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for something like [Scientific.BSP](http://dirac.cnrs-orleans.fr/ScientificPython/ScientificPythonManual/Scientific.BSP-module.html) and [Scientific.MPI](http://dirac.cnrs-orleans.fr/ScientificPython/ScientificPythonManual/Scientific.MPI-module.html)?

The projects you've mentioned certainly could solve the problem at some level. Afterall some of them implement CORBA and CORBA-like specifications which are definitely designed to provide "you even don't know where your code runs on" model of execution. But I couldn't admit that these technologies provide such a simple to use abstraction as `multiprocessing` does. Well, a sprt of, it's something that doesn't have well defined comparison criteria and in general heavily depend on personal tastes and previous experience...